# Error on DataContractAttribute, IExtensibleDataObject, ExtensionDataObject

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, web-services

I got this error on my win forms
'system.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttrubute is not defines' same for 'IExtensibleDataObject, ExtensionDataObject'

I have the following in my app,

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
```

What I did was, I have a web service and I want to debug it, and its easier in a win form app. I copied the code and copied the web reference.

I don't know why this happens.

C# help also welcome

Answer (score 4):

You are probably missing a reference to the `System.Runtime.Serialization` (.NET) assembly. Add it to your project as a reference and it should be all good.

You can also see this in the documentation (MSDN), that `DataContractAttribute`, `ExtensionDataObject` and `IExtensibleDataObject` are defined in the `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` assembly.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.extensiondataobject.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx

Add it to your project reference: go to your project properties, tab "References" and press "Add", go to the tab ".NET" and look for "System.Runtime.Serialization". Now you should be good to go.

[image]